# Select2 Start Matching After First N Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there a way to have the Select2 dropdown appear only after 3 or more chars have been typed?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `minimumInputLength` option to do this.

```
minimumInputLength: 3,
```

You can look here
https://select2.github.io/options.html